# solving for steady state PDE using steady.1D (rootSolve R)

Tags: r

I am trying to obtain a steady state for a spatially-explicit Lotka-Volterra competition model of two competing species (with spatial diffusion). Here is the model (without diffusion term):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations

where I let r1 = r2 = rG & alpha12 = alpha 21 = a. The carrying capacity of species 1 is assumed to vary linearly across space x i.e. K1 = x (while K2 = 0.5). And we assume Neumann BC. The spatial domain x is from 0 to 1.

Here is the example of coding in R for this model:

```
LVcomp1D <- function (time, state, parms, N, Da, x, dx) { 
with (as.list(parms), { 
S1 <- state[1:N] 
S2 <- state[(N+1):(2*N)] 

## Dispersive fluxes; zero-gradient boundaries 
FluxS1 <- -Da * diff(c(S1[1], S1, S1[N]))/dx 
FluxS2 <- -Da * diff(c(S2[1], S2, S2[N]))/dx 

## LV Competition 
InteractS1 <- rG * S1 * (1- (S1/x)- ((a*S2)/x)) 
InteractS2 <- rG * S2 * (1- (S2/(K2))- ((a*S1)/(K2))) 

## Rate of change = -Flux gradient + Interaction 
dS1 <- -diff(FluxS1)/dx + InteractS1 
dS2 <- -diff(FluxS2)/dx + InteractS2 

return (list(c(dS1, dS2))) 
}) 
} 

pars <- c(rG = 1.0, a = 0.8, K2 = 0.5) 
dx <- 0.001 
x <- seq(0, 1, by = dx) 
N <- length(x) 
Da <- 0.001 
state <- c(rep(0.5, N), rep(0.5, N)) 
print(system.time( 
out <- steady.1D (y = state, func = LVcomp1D, parms = pars, 
nspec = 2, N = N, x = x, dx = dx, Da = Da, pos = TRUE) 
)) 

mf <- par(mfrow = c(2, 2)) 
plot(out, grid = x, xlab = "x", mfrow = NULL, 
ylab = "N(x)", main = c("Species 1", "Species 2"), type = "l") 
par(mfrow = mf)
```

The problem is I cannot get the steady state solutions of the model. I keep getting a horizontal line passing through x-axis. Can you please help me since I do not know what is wrong with this code.

Thank you

Comment: Please explain "horizontal line passing through x-axis". Vertical? "y-axis", "..coincident with.."?  Also, I'm guessing `steady.1D is from a package: are we supposed to assume it is "rootSolve"?

Comment: Also explain why this is not a 2d problem?

Comment: Basically when you run this code, you will obtain two plots (for Species 1 and 2, respectively). The abundances of Sp. 1 and 2 will equal to 0 for the entire domain x (i.e. from 0 to 1). So, that is the reason you can just see a horizontal line near x-axis. By the way, steady.1D is from a rootSolve package. (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rootSolve/rootSolve.pdf)

And this is 1D problem since the model consists of spatial diffusion in x only.

Comment: You have two species and dx1/dt  and dx2/dt are functions of the time-dependent variation of the x1 and x2 values. Doesn't make it 2d?

Comment: I would like to obtain the steady-state solutions, whereby the time derivatives are set to zero. Then the diffusion terms can be approximated using finite  difference scheme and the Newton's Method can be used in order to approximate the steady-state solutions for these 2 species. The steady.1D is the steady-state solver in rootSolve package, which utilises Newton's Method.

Comment: Just because you desire a steady state solution does not imply that one exists or that the problem is 1D. I'm reasonably sure this problem is a common one for treatment by fractal methods, and that "steady-state" might not even exist. I think you may need help at CrossValidated.com to improve your understanding of the behavior of such systems. (This is the wrong site for such education.)